# jquery ui dialog draggable on entire dialog not just title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-dialog

Currently jquery ui dialog is draggable only on the titlebar

What's the recommended way to make jquery ui dialog be draggable by the entire dialog instead of just the titlebar?

I just did

```
elem.dialog({draggable: false}).draggable()
```

Anything wrong with this?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Some html would be helpful.

Comment: I would assume it's using a handle for the draggable property. Perhaps there is a configuration setting for this which would make the whole item draggable.

Comment: Does `elem.dialog({draggable: false}).draggable()` work? If so then I'd say that's the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to work - it would probably make the dialog's contents draggable _within_ its dialog frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently jQueryUI prevents the content from being draggable with this code:

```
self.uiDialog.draggable({
    cancel: ".ui-dialog-content, .ui-dialog-titlebar-close",
    handle: ".ui-dialog-titlebar",
     ...
});
```

So, to make the change you require you'll need to access that internal `uiDialog` object and change its settings.

If `dlg` is your dialog content object:

```
$(dlg).data('dialog').uiDialog.draggable('option', {
    cancel: '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close',
    handle: '.ui-dialog-titlebar, .ui-dialog-content'
})
```

will work.

Note that this is futzing with jQueryUI internals and may break if those internals are changed by future updates.

Comment: Using this approach works in terms of draggability, the problem though is that I cannot use the mouse to click into any input controls such as text boxes (only via `TAB`). Depending on what you want to show inside your dialog, Jeffrey's answer might be a better solution.

Answer (score 15):

Well, `elem.dialog({draggable: false}).draggable();` won't work, because as other answers have said, it's not the right element.  However, this will work:

```
    elem.dialog({draggable: false}).parent().draggable();
```

I think it's a better option than fiddling with jquery internals.

Comment: How about set mouse cursor to dragable icon?

Comment: @Kostadin - Do it yourself with CSS.